# Сall repaint() on view

Tags: c++, qt, model-view

There is a view in which the drawing method is redefined. There is also a button, when clicked, the view should call the `repaint()` method. For convenience, in this example, the view is not associated with any data from the model.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QListView>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QPushButton>

class View :public QListView {
public:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) override
    {
        QListView::paintEvent(event);
        QPainter painter(viewport());
        static int x = 10, y = 10;
        painter.drawPixmap(x, y, QPixmap("cheker.png"));
        x += 10;
        y += 10;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    View view;

    QPushButton btn("btn");
    btn.move(100, 300);
    QObject::connect(&btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), &view, SLOT(repaint()));

    btn.show();
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I found that after the first click on the button, `repaint()` is called only once. Pressing the button 2nd 3rd 4th etc. times `repaint()` is not called. Why?

Comment: Try to connect to `view.viewport(), &Widget::update` instead. Calling `update()` of a `QAbstractScrollArea` (or anything derived) is a common error and even documented in [`QAbstractScrollArea`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#details): _Use viewport->update() to update the contents of the viewport instead of update() as all painting operations take place on the viewport._

Comment: Btw. the doc. of [`QWidget::repaint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#repaint) mentions: _We suggest only using repaint() if you need an immediate repaint, for example during animation. In almost all circumstances update() is better, as it permits Qt to optimize for speed and minimize flicker._

Comment: @Scheff **Try to connect to view.viewport(), &Widget::update instead.** I do not understand. What you need to connect to? What's the signal what's the slot?

Comment: @Scheff **Btw. the doc. of QWidget::repaint() mentions: We suggest only using repaint() if you need an immediate repaint, for example during animation. In almost all circumstances update() is better, as it permits Qt to optimize for speed and minimize flicker.** To understand the essence of the problem it does not matter. if you replace `repaint()` on `update()`, the problem remains

Comment: solution: `view.viewport()->repaint();` thx to @Scheff

Comment: Sorry, this was meant as slot in Qt5 style signal connection: `QObject::connect(&btn, &QPushButton::clicked, view.viewport(), &QWidget::update);`. The `update()` should be preferred over `repaint()`. We _do_ animation in Qt but never needed `repaint`. `update()` was always sufficient.